# How to observe changes in HTML classes to change the innerHTML property

Tags: javascript, html, dom-manipulation

I'm trying to change a number on the webpage to display the current page number whenever there is a change in the classes of the DIV element.

```
    <div id="fullpage">
        <div class="hover_color"></div>
        <div id="main_wrapper">
            <!--Section 1-->
            <div class="section" id="section0">
                <h1>Hello.</h1>
            </div>
```

I'm using fullpagejs plugin which dynamically adds classnames to the currently viewed section; in this case, the class = "section" changes to class="section fp-section active fp-completely".

Outside this markup is another div with position:fixed

```
    <div id="inc" class="inc_num">
            <p>00.</p>

    </div>
```

I'm looking to change the value of 01 to 02 when the 2nd section is active and 02 to 03 when 3rd section is active.

I'm running this javascript to achieve this result.

```
const numberShow = function() {
const detectSection = document.getElementsByClassName('section fp-section active fp-completely')[0].id;
const inc = document.getElementById('inc');

switch (detectSection) {
    case section0:
        inc.innerHTML = '00.';
    case section1:
        inc.innerHTML ='01.';
        break;
    case section2:
        inc.innerHTML ='02.';
        break;
    case section3:
        inc.innerHTML ='03.';
        break;
    case section4:
        inc.innerHTML ='04.';
        break;
    case section5:
        inc.innerHTML ='05.';
        break;
    case section6:
        inc.innerHTML ='06.';
        break;

    default:
        break;
}
};
//Call numberShow every 500 millisecs to check current active class and 
//change the number
setInterval(numberShow(), 500);
```

This however, isn't working

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
    let detectSection, detectFooter, section, footer;
    const numberShow = () => {
    detectSection = document.getElementsByClassName('section fp-section active 
    fp-completely');
    if(detectSection !== null){
    section = detectSection[0].id;
    }else{
    detectFooter = document.getElementsByClassName('section fp-auto-height fp- 
    section active fp-completely');
    footer = detectFooter[0].id;
    }
    const num = document.getElementById('inc');


    if(section == 'section0'){
    num.innerHTML ='<p>00.</p><b></b>'; 
     } else if(section == 'section1'){
    num.innerHTML ='<p>01.</p><b></b>'; 
    }else if(section == 'section2'){
    num.innerHTML ='<p>02.</p><b></b>'; 
    }else if(section == 'section3'){
    num.innerHTML ='<p>03.</p><b></b>'; 
    }else if(section == 'section4'){
    num.innerHTML ='<p>04.</p><b></b>'; 
    }else if(section == 'section5'){
    num.innerHTML ='<p>05.</p><b></b>'; 
    }else if(section == 'section6'){
    num.innerHTML ='<p>06.</p><b></b>'; 
    }else if(section == 'section7'){
    num.innerHTML = '';
    }
    }
    setInterval(numberShow, 200);
```

Comment: This is not the way to go at all to observe for a mutation in the DOM, although it will work as expected. Check for this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51775565/how-to-observe-changes-in-html-classes-to-change-the-innerhtml-property#72088082) where it explains how to do it properly, using the Mutation Observer.

Answer (score 0):

You should check [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)

It is doing exactly what you want

Comment: I tried doing that. I'm a complete newbie and I was thinking I'd implement MutationObserver later when I have time to learn that. In the meanwhile, may I know what is going wrong with this above code?

Comment: Right your HTML and JS doesn't match; I mean you have ` <div class="section" id="section0">` only section class-name, but in JS you are queiring `section fp-section active fp-completely`. Can you add some clessname or 'data-' attributu to the div where id will change?

Comment: It happens at run-time. It gets that classname when using the fullpage.js plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`observe()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver/observe#syntax) method of the [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) interface, with the `attributeFilter` option, specifying the attribute names to be monitored (`class` in your case):

```
const observedElement = document.getElementById("observed-element");

const classObserver = new MutationObserver(() => {
  console.log("The class attribute has changed")
});

classObserver.observe(observedElement, {attributeFilter: ["class"]});
```

```js
const observedElement = document.getElementById("observed-element");

const classObserver = new MutationObserver(() => {
  renderClasses();
  alert("The class attribute has changed");
});

classObserver.observe(observedElement, {attributeFilter: ["class"]});

const toggleClassButton = document.getElementById("toggle-class");
toggleClassButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  observedElement.classList.toggle("another-class");
});

function renderClasses() {
  const classes = observedElement.classList;
  const classListElement = document.getElementById("class-list");
  classListElement.innerText = classes;
}

renderClasses();
```

```css
p {
  margin-block: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: fit-content;
  background: lightgreen;
  border: 1px solid green;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

span {
  color: red;
}

button {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<p id="observed-element" class="one-class">I'm the element observed and my classes are: <span id="class-list"></span></p>
<button id="toggle-class">Toggle class "another-class"</button>
```

If you want to observe to all attributes modifications you can pass the `attributes` option set to `true` instead of the `attributeFilter`:

```
classObserver.observe(observedElement, {attributes: true});
```